# Can I check updated row data form oracle in real time?

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I'm developing a web site with Spring framework.

I want to check the updated data(ex. increasing number) from oracle in real time and show it on the jsp page.

Comment: Note that uncommited data won't be visible to other sessions. It means that you can *update* (or insert, or delete) thousands of rows, but nobody except the one who does that will see it happen until commit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need a driver to query the data from the database and then you can display it on your web page. Other than that, your question is a little vague.